# Is this correct? F distribution

Tags: statistics

I was wondering if my answer for part c  of this question is correct? I have attached all needed information. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you are going to paste problems from a _published book_ into Questions here, you should give the author, title, and year of the book.

Comment: These are my teachers homework problems that he has assigned and given the solutions to (and he has not stated that he got them from a book so..I assumed they were his own)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Problem 4(b) you know that $U \sim Chis(4).$
Independently, $Y = X_6^2 + X_7^2 \sim Chis(2).$
Thus in 3(c), $\frac{Y/2}{U/4} = \frac{2Y}{U} \sim F(2,4),$ Snedecor's
F-distribution with numerator df 2 and denominator df 4.
Your answer seems OK, except that you have put in an extra 4.

*Note:* The F disstribution is useful for testing from data whether two
normal distributions have equal variances. Also, in the analysis of
variance. Fisher introduced the idea of this distribution, calling
it the variance-ratio distribution; Snedecor put it into the form
usually used today.

I assume you got Student's t-distributions in 3(a) and (b).